# Resetting a variable value for each insert

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a PL/SQL function as follows:

```
create FUNCTION Test
return number
IS cnpParmId NUMBER;
good VARCHAR(1) := 'F';
exist VARCHAR(1) := 'F';
begin
good  := 'F';
exist := 'F';
loop
   select schema1.parm_id_seq.nextval into cnpParmId from dual;
   begin
      select 'T' into good from dual where cnpParmId not in (select PARM_ID from schema1.mytable1);
      exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then good := 'F';
   end;
   exit when good = 'T';
end loop;
return cnpParmId;
end;
```

Now using this function am trying to insert values into tables:

```
declare
var1 number := Test;

BEGIN
INSERT INTO schema1.tbl
(PARM_ID, PARM_NAM, PARM_VAL_TXT, PARM_USAGE_TYPE_CD, PARM_USAGE_VAL_TXT, CRTE_TS, CRTE_USER_ID, LST_UPDT_TS, LST_UPDT_USER_ID, SITE_CD)
SELECT var1, 'VEL_INT_TYPE_MI', 'Minutes', 'RTS', NULL, SYSDATE, 'ilogdmgr', SYSDATE, 'ilogdmgr', NULL from dual;

INSERT INTO schema1.tbl
   (PARM_ID, PARM_NAM, PARM_VAL_TXT, PARM_USAGE_TYPE_CD, PARM_USAGE_VAL_TXT, 
    CRTE_TS, CRTE_USER_ID, LST_UPDT_TS, LST_UPDT_USER_ID, SITE_CD)
   select var1, 'Hours', 48, 'RTS', NULL, SYSDATE, 'ilogdmgr', SYSDATE, 'ilogdmgr', NULL from dual;

INSERT INTO schema1.tbl
   (PARM_ID, PARM_NAM, PARM_VAL_TXT, PARM_USAGE_TYPE_CD, PARM_USAGE_VAL_TXT, 
    CRTE_TS, CRTE_USER_ID, LST_UPDT_TS, LST_UPDT_USER_ID, SITE_CD)
   select var1, 'Days', 45, 'RTS', NULL, SYSDATE, 'ilogdmgr', SYSDATE, 'ilogdmgr', NULL from dual;
end;
```

The first insert takes the value that is returned from the function. I want the value to be refreshed for the second insert. I am expecting that the second insert will go to the function and returns another value. But thats now happening here. The same value is taken and the query fails with unique constraint index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try `select test(),...  instead of select var1`

Comment: It Worked. Thanks :)